# Can we compute higher derivatives of an InverseFunction?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, inverse-function

We can define an InverseFunction even when the inverse can't be expressed in closed form.

```
f[x_]:=1.1*x+Sin[x];
fInverse=InverseFunction[1.1*#+Sin[#]&];
Plot[{f[x],fInverse[x],x},{x,0,14},
   PlotStyle->{Blue,Brown,{Gray,Dashed}},
   PlotRange->{{0,14},{0,14}},AspectRatio->1
]
```

[image: plot]
We can also compute the first derivative of fInverse.

```
fInverse'[3.46]
(* 9.91112 *)
```

However, trying to compute the second derivative doesn't work.

```
fInverse''[3.46]
(* -4.15922 (9.91112+(0& (InverseFunction')[1.1 #1+Sin[#1]&])[3.46]) *)
```

Is it possible to compute higher derivatives using an approach similar to computing the first derivative? I am using Version 12.0.0. Are any later versions able to compute higher derivatives of such an InverseFunction?

Comment: You are interested in the fully numerical approach, right?

Comment: On V12.3 it's working for me. `fInverse''[3.46]` gives `-41.2225`.

Comment: It is interesting that the documentation for `InverseFunction` gives an example of `InverseFunction[(a # + b)/(c # + d) &]` which works, your example of `InverseFunction[1.1*#+Sin[#]&]` does not. This behavior should be documented. The answer by Bob Hanlon shows that using `InverseFunction[f]` works. I don't understand why the difference.

Comment: The following will run increasingly faster as the order of the derivative grows for the 4th order and up: ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression[InverseFunction[g]''''[x]] /. g -> f /. x -> 3.46 // First`` (Assumes `g` and `x` are undefined.)

Comment: I presume you've already seen [this article](https://doi.org/10.2307/2695472)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x_] := 1.1*x + Sin[x];

fInverse = InverseFunction[f];

Through[{fInverse, fInverse', fInverse''}[x]]
```

[image]

```
% /. x -> 3.46

(* {3.18395, 9.91112, -41.2225} *)

Plot[{fInverse[x], fInverse'[x], fInverse''[x]}, {x, 0, 6},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.25, .75}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** In my version the longer form also works

```
Clear[fInverse]

fInverse = InverseFunction[1.1*# + Sin[#] &];

{fInverse[x], fInverse'[x], fInverse''[x]}

(* {InverseFunction[1.1 #1 + Sin[#1] &][x], 
 1/(1.1 + Cos[InverseFunction[1.1 #1 + Sin[#1] &][x]]), 
 Sin[InverseFunction[1.1 #1 + Sin[#1] &][x]]/(1.1 + 
    Cos[InverseFunction[1.1 #1 + Sin[#1] &][x]])^3} *)

% /. x -> 3.46

(* {3.18395, 9.91112, -41.2225} *)
```

Comment: At least with version 12.0.0 we need to use  InverseFunction[f] rather than InverseFunction[1.1*#+Sin[#]&].

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a numerical approach, it is the classical case for the use of `NDSolve` or `NDSolveValue`

```
f[x_] := 1.1*x + Sin[x]
gg = NDSolveValue[{g'[y] == 1/f'[g[y]], g[0] == 0}, g, {y, 0, 10}]
Plot[{gg[x], gg'[x], gg''[x]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

The verification can be done as follows

```
Plot[{f[gg[x]]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Something seems to be wrong here: `Plot[{f[gg[x]],x }, {x, 0, 10}]` should give 
`Identity` I think!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Done, the post is updated. Thank you for checking everything carefully!